For a proper Lie group $G$ acting on a complete Riemannian manifold $M$ by isometry, can we find $p'$ close to $p\in M, d(p,p')>d_{M/G}([p], [p'])?$
Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, and the Lie group $G$ with $1 \le dim(G) < dim(M)$ acts on $M$ isometrically and properly. Using the metric on $M,$ we define the metric on the quotient $Q:=M/G$ by $d_Q([p_1], [p_2]):= min_{g \in G}d(p_1,g.p_2).$
It seems to me that given any $p\in M,$ and given any $\eta>0,\exists p'\in B(p;\eta)$ so that $d(p,p') > d_Q([p], [p']).$ I'm trying to prove this or at least convince myself that it's true. Below is my effort, could you please check if my argument is correct?
Remark: First off, the claim is not true if $G$ is discrete: consider the $G:=\mathbb{Z}$-action on $M:=\mathbb{R}$ for example with $Q:=\mathbb{S}^1.$ Here of course the interval $ (-\pi,\pi)\subset \mathbb{R}$ containing $0$ is mapped isometrically and thus $d(p,p') = d_{Q:=\mathbb{S}^1}([p], [p']) \forall -\pi < p,p' < \pi.$
Question 1: But when $G$ is not discrete, the orbit $O_p:=G.p=[p]$ is also not discrete and in fact an embedded submanifold of dimension $dim(G).$ So there's a point $p'\in O_p: 0<d(p,p')<\eta,i.e. p'\in B(p,\eta)\setminus \{p\}$ but in this case: $d([p],[p'])=0$ since $p'\in O_p.$ So $d(p,p') > d_Q([p], [p']). $ I think this wraps up the proof: is my argument correct?
Question 2: But even if the above argument is right, I'm not fully satisfied with the fact that $d([p],[p'])=0.$ So could we perhaps find another point $p'\in B(p,\eta)\setminus \{O_p\}$ so that $d(p,p') > d_Q([p], [p']). $ Is yes, how do we find this $p'?$
